# How do I add a file in a subfolder to a new repository?

Tags: github

I have a repository for a website and it has two separate remotes. One is for the website files and one for datasets and R scripts to make some data in my blog posts reproducible and archived for the future.

My local file structure looks like this.

```
-Website
|
|--website-files/posts/blog-post1
                     |/blog-post2
                     |r_script.R
```

The folder `Website` has two remotes one - `origin` -  for the website, and one - `blog-post` - for the dumping ground for my replication files.

So, because I have cleanly added a second remote, I tried to add the file `r_script.R` and push it to the remote `blog-post`.

`git add website-files/posts/r_script.R`

Then, though, when I check the status, git status shows the file name as *untracked* listed as 
`../../r_script.R`

The precise question: How do I add a file in a subfolder to be tracked and then to push its own unique remote? Note, when I copy `r_script.R` to the folder `Website`, and run `git add r_script.R` it shows up as a staged file ready for committing.

But I would really rather keep it in the subfolder to keep it clean.

Maybe should I add the repo `blog-post` as a submodule to the subfolder `website-files/posts/` or something like that?

Comment: That is really weird coz - `git add website-files/posts/r_script.R` should do the trick,  is there a possibility that somehow - `website-files/posts` is added to the ignore list in .gitignore ?

Comment: OK, I was able to add the files, they are listed as staged and I tried to push to `blog-post` but then I get this error. 

``
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.```

Comment: I think what is happening is that there is a .readme file in the repository `blog-post` but I don't have that in my local repository folder `Website`, and I don't really want it. Is there a way to force a push? Or delete the readme file? Or is something else the matter?